# How to use a partial function composed with orElse as a udf in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

As the question states, I would like to use a partial function, composed with orElse, as a udf in spark. Here is an example that can be run in spark shell:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(1 to 15).toDF("num")
df.show

//Testing out a normal udf - this works
val gt5: (Int => String) = num => (num > 5).toString
val gt5Udf = udf(gt5)
df.withColumn("gt5", gt5Udf(col("num"))).show

//Now create a udf of a partial function composed with orElse
val baseline: PartialFunction[Int, String] = { case _ => "baseline" }
val ge3: PartialFunction[Int, String] = { case x if x >= 3 => ">=3" }
val ge7: PartialFunction[Int, String] = { case x if x >= 7 => ">=7" }
val ge12: PartialFunction[Int, String] = { case x if x >= 12 => ">=12" }

val composed: PartialFunction[Int, String] = ge12 orElse ge7 orElse ge3 orElse baseline
val composedUdf = udf(composed)

//This fails (but this is what I'd like to do)
df.withColumn("pf", composedUdf(col("num"))).show

//Use a partial function not composed with orElse - this works
val baselineUdf = udf(baseline)
df.withColumn("pf", baselineUdf(col("num"))).show
```

I'm currently running this on a three node standalone cluster with the following configuration:

- spark: 1.6.0
- hdfs: 2.4.1
- scala: 2.10.5

I found what I think is a clue in this answer: [Why Scala can serialize Function but not PartialFunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801305/why-scala-can-serialize-function-but-not-partialfunction)

so I tried:

```
scala> composed.isInstanceOf[Serializable]
res: Boolean = false

scala> composedUdf.isInstanceOf[Serializable]
res: Boolean = true

scala> baseline.isInstanceOf[Serializable]
res: Boolean = true

scala> baselineUdf.isInstanceOf[Serializable]
res: Boolean = true
```

I'm getting fuzzy here, but it seems that composing a partial function with orElse removes the serialization?

I think the most informative errors are:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
...
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.PartialFunction$OrElse
...
```

How do I fix that? Or am I off base?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Interesting problem that I wish I had an answer to! I don't. What might be useful to you is that UDFs in Spark are black boxes for the Catalyst Optimizer and should be used with care since they are not optimized. Often you may get better results with the existing functions of Spark SQL. Also `(1 to 15).toDF("num")` works too.

Comment: Ugh. While `PartialFunction` is just a trait, `orElse` has to return a concrete `PartialFunction` - so it conjures one up on the spot, except that that class ends up being not serializable (even if there is not good reason for it not to be). There lies your problem.

Comment: It should work if you lift it and wrap it in another function, like that `val composed: Int => Option[String] = x => (ge12 orElse ge7 orElse ge3 orElse baseline).lift.apply(x)`, if that's something you could live with.

Comment: This is fixed in Scala 2.12.

Comment: @lpiepiora You mention "if that's something you can live with". Did you have another downside in mind beyond the fact that UDFs can't be optimized by the Catalyst Optimizer?

Comment: @ajp619 also the fact, that the composition will be evaluated each time on each invocation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work if you lift it and wrap it in an another function.

```
val composed: Int => Option[String] = 
  x => (ge12 orElse ge7 orElse ge3 orElse baseline).lift.apply(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't directly address your problem I would like to suggest and alternative solution using SQL functions.

First you'll have to import required functions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{when, lit}
```

and some `implicits` for brevity:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

Next you can express the same conditions as in your code:

```
val baseline = lit("baseline")
val ge3 = when($"num" >= 3,  ">=3")
val ge7 = when($"num" >= 7, ">=7")
val ge12 = when($"num" >= 12, ">=12")

val composed = ge12 otherwise (ge7 otherwise (ge3 otherwise baseline))
```

In this form it a little bit less elegant but you can without any effort compose expression like this using standard collection API (`foldLeft` / `foldRight`) and, [unlike UDFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925575/how-to-use-a-partial-function-composed-with-orelse-as-a-udf-in-spark#comment67135333_39925575), result can be optimized by the Catalyst Optimizer.